# Getting the product detail created on google console dynamically

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have created a subscription product on google console , now i have to fetch  the product details like title and price of the product and use the fetched details to set it on Subscription page UI . I am doing this because i want everything dynamic suppose if i changed the price of my subscription it will reflect instantly on my app. How to fetch the product detail created on console is there any google api to call or is there any other method provide by billing library.

Comment: _Hello B! You need to add more details in your question so other can understand what is exactly the problem. Also add some more code and show us what have you tried._

Comment: added some more detail